# Convert an existing React Component into a Webcomponent?

Tags: reactjs, web-component

My aim is to use convert a react component say Header.tsx into a Webcomponent and use it inside App.tsx. Like this

```
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <my-header/>
   </ThemeProvider>
```

I'm trying to use [react-to-webcomponent](https://github.com/bitovi/react-to-webcomponent) package . But I'm not clear how to use it.

Do I need to add

```
const HeaderComp = reactToWebComponent(Header, React, ReactDOM);

customElements.define("my-header", HeaderComp);
```

inside the Header file? How do I register/import the webcomponent then?